# mariadb database entry using expect script

Tags: expect

I want to add mariadb database entry automatically, while using expect script i am having some error.
my expect script :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect 
spawn /usr/bin/mysql -u root -p

expect "Enter password:"
send "123456 \r"

expect "MariaDB [(none)]>"
send "create database zabbixdb character set utf8;\r"

expect "MariaDB [(none)]>"
send "grant all privileges on zabbixdb.* to 'zabbixuser'@'localhost' identified by '123456';\r"

expect "MariaDB [(none)]>"
send "flush privileges;\r"

expect "MariaDB [(none)]>"
send "exit\r"
```

But it keeps failing, error message:

```
spawn /usr/bin/mysql -u root -p
Enter password: invalid command name "(none)"
    while executing
"(none)"
    invoked from within
"expect "MariaDB [(none)]>""
    (file "./mariadb.sh" line 9)
```

What i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, it looks like the problem is because of un-escaped open square bracket `[`.  If you want to match literal open square bracket, then it should be,

```
"MariaDB \\\[(none)]>"
```

The reason is, `[` is special to both `Tcl` and `Expect`. Unless escaped, it will treated as a command call.

Change your code as,

```
expect "MariaDB \\\[(none)]>"
```

**Note :** We don't need to escape the close square bracket.

Comment: it's not working, new error : 

spawn /usr/bin/mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
send: spawn id exp6 not open
    while executing
"send "create database zabbixdb character set utf8;\r""
    (file "./mariadb.sh" line 8)

Comment: That error message is not due to the script. Check whether it is working manually or not.

Comment: I'd recommend using braces instead of backslashes: `expect {MariaDB [(none)]>}` -- rather easier to read

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue, my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn mysql -u root -p123456


expect "MariaDB \\\[(none)]>"
send "create database zabbixdb character set utf8;\r"


expect "MariaDB \\\[(none)]>"
send "grant all privileges on zabbixdb.* to 'zabbixuser'@'localhost' identified by '123456';\r"


expect "MariaDB \\\[(none)]>"
send "flush privileges;\r"


expect "MariaDB \\\[(none)]>"
send "exit;\r"
```

main problem was password authentication, do not use any space use "-p123456"